# Two curves agree iff they agree on chart

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

Problem: Suppose $c_1,c_2:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow M$ are smooth curves with $c_1(0)=c_2(0)=p$ , where $M$ is a smooth manifold.

Then, $c_1'(0)=c_2'(0)$ if and only if there exists a chart $(U,\phi)\owns p$ such that

$(\phi\circ c_1)'(0)=(\phi\circ c_2)'(0)$

My attempt:

Forward direction: Choose any chart $(U,\phi)$ about $p$. Since $c_1$ is continuous, there exists an open interval $ (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \supseteq I\owns 0$ on which $c_1|_{I}:I\rightarrow U$ is continuous. Assume without loss of generality that $I=(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ . Then by the chain rule, $(\phi \circ c_1)'(0)$=$\phi_{*}(c_{1_{*}}(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}))=\phi_{*}(c_{2_{*}}(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}))=(\phi \circ c_2)'(0)$.

Is the forward direction correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct (provided that ${c_i}_*(\frac d{dt}|_{t=0})=c_i'(0)$ is clear).

Comment: What is the actual definition of $c’(0)$? Without that, who knows …

Comment: @TedShifrin $c'(0)=c_{*}(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0})$

Comment: OK, sure. It's an odd statement. Note that you've proved that the equation holds in *every* chart, as opposed to just one particular one.

Comment: I agree. But since it holds for every chart, then since the atlas is assumed to be non empty, it must hold for some chart, right?